# Aggregate string variable using summarise and across function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

df_input is the input file, and the ideal output file is df_output.

```
df_input <- data.frame(id  = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                       party = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"), 
                       winner= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
                           

df_output <- data.frame(id  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                        party = c("A","B","C","D,E","F_G_H","I","J","K","L","M"),
                        winner_sum = c(1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Previously the code worked using the "summarise_at" function as follows:

```
df_output <- df_input %>%
  dplyr::group_by_at(.vars = vars(id)) %>%
  {left_join(
    dplyr::summarise_at(., vars(party), ~ str_c(., collapse = ",")),
    dplyr::summarise_at(., vars(winner), funs(sum))
  )}
```

But it no longer works as it seems both "summarise_at" and "funs" has been deprecated.

I am trying to replicate using across with dplyr (1.0.10), but I am getting an error. Here is my attempt:

```
df_output <- df_input %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(winner, sum, na.rm=T)) %>%
  summarise(across(party, str_c(., collapse = ",")))
```

I have multiple numeric and character variables,s not just one, as in the example. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need `across` if we need to apply different functions on single columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_input %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(party = str_c(party, collapse = ","),
        winner_sum = sum(winner))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      id party winner_sum
   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
 1     1 A              1
 2     2 B              1
 3     3 C              1
 4     4 D,E            2
 5     5 F,G,H          3
 6     6 I              1
 7     7 J              1
 8     8 K              1
 9     9 L              1
10    10 M              1
```

---

If there are multiple 'party', 'winner' columns, loop `across` them in a single `summarise` as after the first `summarise` we have only the summarised column with the group column

```
df_input %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(winner, sum, na.rm=TRUE),
            across(party, ~ str_c(.x, collapse = ",")), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      id winner party
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>
 1     1      1 A    
 2     2      1 B    
 3     3      1 C    
 4     4      2 D,E  
 5     5      3 F,G,H
 6     6      1 I    
 7     7      1 J    
 8     8      1 K    
 9     9      1 L    
10    10      1 M
```

NOTE: If the columns have a simplar prefix then use `starts_with` to select all those columns i.e. `across(starts_with("party"),` or if there are different column names - `across(c(party, othercol),` or if the functions applied are based on their type - `across(where(is.numeric), sum,, na.rm = TRUE)`

```
df_input %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE),
             across(where(is.character), str_c, collapse = ","),
     .groups = 'drop')
```